# Django get all objects that contains a pk of a many to many relationship

Tags: python, django

I have the following model and I need to retrieve all the subscriptions that have among their connected subscriptions a subscription (of which I know the **`primary key`**)

> In practice I need all the subscriptions that contains a subscription in their `connected_subscription` field

```
Subscription(models.Model):
  connected_subscriptions=models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)
```

How can I retrieve all the subscriptions?

```
Subscription.objects.filter(connected_subscription__???=subscription_key)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Subscription.objects.filter(connected_subscriptions=pk_of_the_object)
```

where *`pk_of_the_object`* is the primary key of the related object.

This works since Django will make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (likely optimized to an `INNER JOIN`) on the junction table between the subscriptions, and then filter on the linked `Subscription`s.